# How to move elements within picturebox?

Tags: winforms, picturebox

Is there any simple way to move picture parts (any stuff created with `DrawImage` or `DrawString`)?

My smart idea:
Override `DrawImage(DrawString)` method adding ability to store width, height, left, top, of drawn image (and may be boolean variable 'sizable' if I use `DrawImage` method) to a list of objects. Attach function "WhatToMove" to PictureBox's `MouseMove` event, which walks through a list of stored rectangle objects, detects what rectangle cursor is over, in case of resizeable rectangle detect if cursor is over any of rectangle's borders and pass this stuff as parameters to the `MouseDown` function, when I click. Then `MouseDown` function will attach new function "MoverResizer" to `MouseMove` event, which redraws picture box with moved or resized parts of image, updates proper rectangle object in list, and also detachs "WhatToMove" from `MouseMove`. On `MouseUp` and Leave events of PictureBox detach "MoverResizer" and attach "WhatToMove".

If you think this idea can live you will really help me if tell me how to override DrawImage.

My dumb idea:

Create Labels without text and with borders and locate them over PictureBox right over proper image parts. Then make them draggable and sizeable with their own events. Then translate positions of labels to positions of parts of picture and redraw picturebox. This is simply but I think not so perfect as method above.

Comment: I have realized dumb idea with visual basic power pack rectangles.